# Nvidia Binary Driver Crashes system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an HP TouchSmart iq506 All-in-One PC (fairly old, about 12 years to be more precise) that has an MXM based GPU, the Nvidia GeForce 9300m GS. 
  The issue I'm referring to started when I first installed GNU/Linux onto it, namely Xubuntu, and about 2 mins after the desktop finaly loaded, the system completely froze up. Although, I did notice that if I moved the mouse around, there would be these weird artifacts at the top of the screen, and they would respond to the movement of the mouse.

After a few more installations (thinking that this would resolve it), the issue persisted. So, as a finally last-ditch effort, I decided to NOT check the ticker to install prop software and drivers (for wifi hardware and graphics cards or whatever it says)... and presto! It boots and works! YAY!

After some time, I decided to use "additional drivers" to switch over to the prop driver, and of course, it ended up doing as it did before... freezing up. So of course I switched back to the open-source driver. The prop driver that it wants to use is the Nvidia Binary driver 340.107. The open-source driver its using now is the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau.

But (I shouldn't start a sentence off like that should I?), I have started to notice that I am not getting the same level of graphics performance as I was when Windont was installed on it, and it was using the correct drivers.

I want to use the correct driver for this thing, but is there a way to do this? Without it freezing up? What should I do to find out whats going on? Is there a command to do this?